# Why am I getting cors error when I have defined it?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

```
Access to fetch at 'localhost:3000/loginundefined' (redirected from 'http://localhost:4000/login') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.
```

```js
var cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());
```

I have added cors in my backend but this errors shows up when I try to login, anyone might have a clue why?

Comment: Is your route meant to be named loginundefined?

Comment: no, it's login only